# Type Mismatch with Kotlin Generic Adapter

Tags: android, kotlin, generics, android-recyclerview, adapter

I'm trying to create a Base Adapter class, which can be extended by all other RecyclerView adapters, since they don't differ much from each other.

Here's my `BaseAdapter` class:

```
private const val IS_EMPTY = 0
private const val IS_NOT_EMPTY = 1

abstract class BaseAdapter<T>(
    @LayoutRes open val layoutId: Int,
    private val dataList: ArrayList<T>?
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<BaseViewHolder<Any>>() {

    abstract fun setViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup): BaseViewHolder<Any>
    abstract fun bind(containerView: View, item: T)

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): BaseViewHolder<Any> {
        return setViewHolder(parent)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: BaseViewHolder<Any>, position: Int) {
        bind(holder.containerView, dataList!![position])
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = dataList!!.size

    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int = if (dataList!!.size == 0) IS_EMPTY else IS_NOT_EMPTY
}
```

Here's my `BaseViewHolder` class:

```
abstract class BaseViewHolder<in T: Any>(override val containerView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(containerView),
    LayoutContainer
```

A snippet from the class (`LessonsRecyclerViewAdapter`)  where I'm trying to implement it:

```
override fun setViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup): BaseViewHolder<Any> {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(layoutId, parent, false)
        return LessonsViewHolder(view)
        //Type mismatch: Required: BaseViewHolder<Any> Found: LessonsRecyclerViewAdapter.LessonsViewHolder
    }
```

`LessonsViewHolder` is just an empty class, extending `BaseViewHolder`:

```
class LessonsViewHolder(override val containerView: View): BaseViewHolder<Lesson>(containerView)
```

Why am I getting Type Mismatch Error, when `LessonsViewHolder` extends `BaseViewHolder`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that's because you're mixing type `T` and `Any`, try this:
BaseViewHolder

```
abstract class BaseViewHolder<T>(override val containerView: View) :
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder(containerView),
    LayoutContainer
```

BaseViewAdapter

```
abstract class BaseAdapter<T>(
    @LayoutRes open val layoutId: Int,
    private val dataList: ArrayList<T>?
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<BaseViewHolder<T>>() {

    abstract fun setViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup): BaseViewHolder<T>
    abstract fun bind(containerView: View, item: T)

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): BaseViewHolder<T> {
        return setViewHolder(parent)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: BaseViewHolder<T>, position: Int) {
        bind(holder.containerView, dataList!![position])
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = dataList!!.size

    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int =
        if (dataList!!.size == 0) IS_EMPTY else IS_NOT_EMPTY
}
```